# Espresso RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem Error

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to implement an instrumented test in one of my screens that has a recycler view. I don't seem to have problems when I use `scrollTo()`, but when I start to use `actionOnItem()` using the same view matcher, I get a runtime exception.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Test Code**

```
@Test
public void nextButton_disabledWhilePhoneNumberInvalid () {
    onView(withId(R.id.countrycodepicker_enterphonenumber_ccp)).perform(click());

    // This is working
    // onView(withId(R.id.recycler_countryDialog))
    //         .perform(scrollTo(hasDescendant(first(withText("Philippines (PH)")))));

    // This is also working
    // onView(withId(R.id.recycler_countryDialog))
    //         .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click()));

    // This is not working and is causing a PerformException
    onView(withId(R.id.recycler_countryDialog))
            .perform(actionOnItem(hasDescendant(first(withText("Philippines (PH)"))), click()));

}

private <T> Matcher<T> first(final Matcher<T> matcher) {
    return new BaseMatcher<T>() {
        boolean isFirst = true;

        @Override
        public boolean matches(final Object item) {
            if (isFirst && matcher.matches(item)) {
                isFirst = false;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("should return first matching item");
        }
    };
}
```

**Runtime Error**

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 

'performing ViewAction: single click on item matching: holder with view: has descendant: should return first matching item' on view 'with id: com.example:id/recycler_countryDialog'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at com.example.EnterPhoneNumberScreenTest.nextButton_disabledWhilePhoneNumberInvalid(EnterPhoneNumberScreenTest.java:53)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:232)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**RecyclerView Adapter Code [(pulled from the third party library I'm using)](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/blob/fdf0956feedcb9feecd5471d74ae7300ae67c04f/ccp/src/main/java/com/hbb20/CountryCodeAdapter.java)**

```
class CountryCodeAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryCodeAdapter.CountryCodeViewHolder> {
    List<Country> filteredCountries = null, masterCountries = null;
    TextView textView_noResult;
    CountryCodePicker codePicker;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    EditText editText_search;
    Dialog dialog;
    Context context;

    CountryCodeAdapter(Context context, List<Country> countries, CountryCodePicker codePicker, final EditText editText_search, TextView textView_noResult, Dialog dialog) {
        this.context = context;
        this.masterCountries = countries;
        this.codePicker = codePicker;
        this.dialog = dialog;
        this.textView_noResult = textView_noResult;
        this.editText_search = editText_search;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.filteredCountries = getFilteredCountries("");
        setSearchBar();
    }

    private void setSearchBar() {
        if (codePicker.isSelectionDialogShowSearch()) {
            setTextWatcher();
        } else {
            editText_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * add textChangeListener, to apply new query each time editText get text changed.
     */
    private void setTextWatcher() {
        if (this.editText_search != null) {
            this.editText_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    applyQuery(s.toString());
                }
            });

            if(codePicker.isKeyboardAutoPopOnSearch()) {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (inputMethodManager != null) {
                    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filter country list for given keyWord / query.
     * Lists all countries that contains @param query in country's name, name code or phone code.
     *
     * @param query : text to match against country name, name code or phone code
     */
    private void applyQuery(String query) {


        textView_noResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        //if query started from "+" ignore it
        if (query.length() > 0 && query.charAt(0) == '+') {
            query=query.substring(1);
        }

        filteredCountries= getFilteredCountries(query);

        if (filteredCountries.size() == 0) {
            textView_noResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private List<Country> getFilteredCountries(String query) {
        List<Country> tempCountryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        if(codePicker.preferredCountries!=null && codePicker.preferredCountries.size()>0) {
            for (Country country : codePicker.preferredCountries) {
                if (country.isEligibleForQuery(query)) {
                    tempCountryList.add(country);
                }
            }

            if (tempCountryList.size() > 0) { //means at least one preferred country is added.
                Country divider = null;
                tempCountryList.add(divider);
            }
        }

        for (Country country : masterCountries) {
            if (country.isEligibleForQuery(query)) {
                tempCountryList.add(country);
            }
        }
        return tempCountryList;
    }

    @Override
    public CountryCodeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recycler_country_tile, viewGroup, false);
        CountryCodeViewHolder viewHolder = new CountryCodeViewHolder(rootView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CountryCodeViewHolder countryCodeViewHolder, final int i) {
        countryCodeViewHolder.setCountry(filteredCountries.get(i));
        countryCodeViewHolder.getMainView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                codePicker.setSelectedCountry(filteredCountries.get(i));
                if (view != null && filteredCountries.get(i)!=null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filteredCountries.size();
    }

    class CountryCodeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout_main;
        TextView textView_name, textView_code;
        ImageView imageViewFlag;
        LinearLayout linearFlagHolder;
        View divider;
        public CountryCodeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            relativeLayout_main = (RelativeLayout) itemView;
            textView_name = (TextView) relativeLayout_main.findViewById(R.id.textView_countryName);
            textView_code = (TextView) relativeLayout_main.findViewById(R.id.textView_code);
            imageViewFlag = (ImageView) relativeLayout_main.findViewById(R.id.image_flag);
            linearFlagHolder = (LinearLayout) relativeLayout_main.findViewById(R.id.linear_flag_holder);
            divider = relativeLayout_main.findViewById(R.id.preferenceDivider);
        }

        public void setCountry(Country country) {
            if(country!=null) {
                divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView_code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearFlagHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView_name.setText(country.getName() + " (" + country.getNameCode().toUpperCase() + ")");
                textView_code.setText("+" + country.getPhoneCode());
                imageViewFlag.setImageResource(country.getFlagID());
            }else{
                divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView_code.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linearFlagHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        public RelativeLayout getMainView() {
            return relativeLayout_main;
        }
    }
}
```

**[View Holder Layout](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/blob/fdf0956feedcb9feecd5471d74ae7300ae67c04f/ccp/src/main/res/layout/layout_recycler_country_tile.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_flag_holder"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/google_1x"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/google_1x"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_flag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/flag_india" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_countryName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linear_flag_holder"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_code"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linear_flag_holder"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView_code"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="India (IN)"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="+91"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        android:textDirection="ltr" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/preferenceDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#898989"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update 2**

If I use allOf instead of the custom first Matcher, I'll get an error due to a duplicate sub-view because the adapter is reusing the previous item as a "divider"

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'performing ViewAction: single click on item matching: holder with view: has descendant: (with text: is "Philippines (PH)")' on view 'with id: com.sample:id/recycler_countryDialog'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at com.sample.EnterPhoneNumberScreenTest.nextButton(EnterPhoneNumberScreenTest.java:59)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: has descendant: (with text: is "Philippines (PH)")' on view 'RecyclerView{id=2131689704, res-name=recycler_countryDialog, visibility=VISIBLE, width=714, height=1354, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=21.0, y=269.0, child-count=12}'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ScrollToViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:373)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:226)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found more than one sub-view matching holder with view: has descendant: (with text: is "Philippines (PH)")

*** Matched ViewHolder item at position: 1 ***

View Hierarchy:
+>RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=2131689698, res-name=linear_flag_holder, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-->AppCompatImageView{id=2131689699, res-name=image_flag, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+->AppCompatTextView{id=2131689706, res-name=textView_countryName, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Philippines (PH), input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+->AppCompatTextView{id=2131689707, res-name=textView_code, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=+63, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+->View{id=2131689708, res-name=preferenceDivider, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|


*** Matched ViewHolder item at position: 2 ***

View Hierarchy:
+>RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=2131689698, res-name=linear_flag_holder, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-->AppCompatImageView{id=2131689699, res-name=image_flag, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+->AppCompatTextView{id=2131689706, res-name=textView_countryName, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Philippines (PH), input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+->AppCompatTextView{id=2131689707, res-name=textView_code, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=+63, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+->View{id=2131689708, res-name=preferenceDivider, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|

at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ScrollToViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:368)
... 12 more
```

Comment: Can you provide the layouts that you use in your ViewHolders and any additional code that the ViewHolder does programmatically?

Comment: @jdonmoyer I've added the layout as well as the adapter code. The element involved is actually a third party library; I pulled the code from the project GitHub.

Answer (score 6):

[`actionOnItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html#actionOnItem(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.view.View%3E,%20android.support.test.espresso.ViewAction)) actually returns an object which you can call [`atPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.PositionableRecyclerViewAction.html#atPosition(int)) on.  For example, to get the second item at position 1 (i.e. not the first item at position 0), add `.atPosition(1)` as follows:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_countryDialog))
        .perform(actionOnItem<ViewHolder>(hasDescendant(withText("Philippines (PH)")), click()).atPosition(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish with the first() Matcher, but my first guess would be that that is what's causing the issue.

RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem() actually operates on the itemView of your ViewHolder (the root view of R.layout.layout_recycler_country_tile).  Assuming there is only one item with text "Philippines (PH)" removing the 'first' matcher should work because the actionOnItem is already looking at a specific ViewHolder row.  If you do have multiple rows with the same text, I would suggest using allOf() to better target the row that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I've added more info -- unfortunately I can't use allOf() because it will be getting duplicates -- due to how the view holders are being created.

Comment: ahh, I missed that piece... in the second matching view, most of the views in the itemview have visibility GONE... try this: actionOnItem(hasDescendant(allOf(withText("Philippines (PH)"), withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE))), click())

Answer (score -1):

No value passed for parameter 'viewAction' will be reported if using the 2 votes solution